# Port already in use 8080 error prompts in Eclipse but it does work on port 8080 in web browser when running

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Used to run Spring MVC project is Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) using Tomcat 8.5. When I run the project it displays "port already in use error" in console, but when I run on browser localhost:8080/ it works. But when I look in to the 'Servers' section in Eclipse it stopped but I think it is managed by Spring boot configuration that I included in pom.xml. and there the server is started already in port 8080, correct me if I am wrong there.

I am confused what exactly 'Server' section shows in Eclipse project and how we can change the port to something else from Eclipse, if possible?

could someone help me to understand this by explaining what actually happening in the background ?
bs: there's new server folder created out of the workspace when I add new server.
[image: port already in use error, configuration set to 8080]
[image: server is stopped, no port added in .properties file]
[image: but it works on port 8080]

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: but my real confusion is what 'Server' section in Eclipse means? does that the server created by spring boot automatically since I include it in pom.xml or the server which I installed explicitly to my machine?

Comment: also would like to mention that a local server for each project is created, you can see a server folder in my eclipse IDE on top of the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps:

1. Go to run configuration
2. Create new run configuration
3. Go to arguments tab
4. Go to vmArguments
5. there enter:   `-Dserver.port=8081`
6. Click on apply and close.

Instead of `8081` you can put any other port number also.

Comment: it works, but now it's listening to both 8080 andd 8081, output for both urls. why would that not worked when I add the same `-Dserver.port=8081` in .properties file?

Comment: if you are using windows. Open task manager and kill all processes of `java.exe`. Then try to run on eclipse. It will work. Sometimes i face the same issue i resolve it like this.

Comment: @AM.Firnas You have to manually kill the process running on port 8080.

Comment: I am using Amazon linux.

Answer (score 0):

Manually going to localhost:8080 works *because* of the error message. Another process, likely another copy of Tomcat, is already running and listening on that port--it's what is sending a response back to your browser. The right side of the server editor you're showing in the first image has the Ports section visible. That is where you can change the Port numbers for the instance you launch from Eclipse.

Comment: yes, there's another instance running on which is because of I have included spring boot dependencies basically, my question comes when I change the port from Eclipse it does not really change, that;s my problem.

Comment: Do you have plug-ins installed for working with Spring Boot? The editor you have open only affects Tomcat when launched from the Servers view, and resources launched using the Run on Server and Debug on Server actions. For Spring Boot you'd modify the `application.properties` or `application.yml` file.

Comment: yes, there's plugin installed via `<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>` what server it's showing actually under 'Servers' section in Eclipse ? is that created by the spring boot plugin or already installed tomcat server on my machine?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you have plug-ins for Spring Boot installed in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hanging java process that listens on that port.

Find the process by port and kill it.

for linux you can use `fuser -k 8080/tcp`

for windows `netstat -ano | findstr :PORT_NUMBER` to get the PID and then kill it

apart from that you can use `JavaVisualVM` to track all java applications running on your machine

[image]

Comment: alright, I will look into that. but my real confusion is what 'Server' section in Eclipse means? does that the server created by spring boot automatically since I include it in pom.xml or the server which I installed explicitly to my machine?

Comment: the server is not sub-process of eclipse, this is why eclipse can't track it. even if you run the server withing eclipse it is still not guaranteed that it will be tracked properly. This issue is observed with other IDEs also, like intellij. Issues like there appear from time to time, I just go used to them apparently

Answer (score 0):

I would happy ifsomeone vote up this question, I feel it's a valid question as there are some confusion might raise as many configurations options available like embedded server vs stand alone server, spring boot behaviour when it comes to loading the relevant dependencies to class path.

happy if someone vote this question up, so I keep continue my profile updated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the answer after spending time on research and trail & error.Thanks for everyone who contributed to this question, that's what it makes me to spend more time to understand the problem. Since actually I am a beginner on work on creating spring project from scratch. Please bear with me.

Actually I would like to point out these.

1) This project is initialized from https://start.spring.io/, so that means it is spring boot based project, not a plain spring-MVC project(with those .XML files).

2) I have been running it on an embedded Tomcat server where I should follow the practice when I run the application. one approach is `./mvnw spring-boot:run` and another approach is creating a `.JAR` file by `./mvnw clean package` and run it.

I did the mistake by attaching the another Tomcat(stand-alone) server when I run the application via Eclipse. So that is wrong.

Here you can see now there is no server displays under 'Server' section in Eclipse but when I run the application it runs successfully (see the console) and listening to default port 8080 also if I want to change the port that is possible by passing as a argument.`-Dserver.port=8081` or every other options you guys suggested.
[image: no any stand-alone server]
[image: but application runs on top of embedded server]
[image: for default port:8080]

**any suggestions for improving this highly appreciated.** please vote if you feel good about my findings.

references:

1. [what-is-spring-boot](https://www.zoltanraffai.com/blog/what-is-spring-boot/)
2. [serving-web-content](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)